# Rails - getting the value out from the view form into a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my form the user has to select a category for his post.

```
  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :category, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

(Currently I am using text-input instead of a drop-down list)

Posts belong to categories

```
@post = @category.posts.build(post_params)
```

However I can't understand how to get the category value out of that field.
I have tried passing a number, to find_by id, and string to find_by name.

```
@category = Category.find(params[:category]) #returns no Categoy with nil id
@category = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]) #returns no method error
```

any help would be appreciated

Edit:

Form code

```
<%= form_for [@company, @post], :html => { :class => "form-posts"} do |f| %>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <%= f.text_field :text, class: "form-control", placeholder: "text", required: true %>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                    </span>
                    <%= f.text_field :date, 
                                      class: "form-control", 
                                      value: @today, 
                                      data: {behaviour: "datepicker"},
                                      required: true %>
                </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :comment, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Comment (optional)" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :category, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit 'Add', class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Edit 2

controller:

form:

```
<%= f.text_field :category, class: "form-control" %>
```

def create

```
@company = current_user.companies.find(params[:company_id])
@category = @company.categories(params[:category])
@post = @category.posts.build(post_params)
```

debugger:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "transaction"=>{"text"=>"lalala", "date"=>"11.11.2013", "comment"=>"", "category"=>"5"}, "commit"=>"Add post", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"posts", "company_id"=>"2"}

undefined method `transactions'
```

Comment: Can you paste your complete form? `params[:category]` should work

Comment: edited. Nothing special about the form though IMO

Comment: Add a `debugger` on your controller method and print params: `p params` and you'll see how's your parameters.

Comment: Or take a look at the development log. probably it will be something like params[:post][:category]

Comment: Can you paste your params response overhere.

Comment: edited. I don't think I'm passing the value to the controller correctly

Comment: When and where are you trying to retrieve `params[:category]`? After the submit action? Then it should be undefined.

Comment: in the "create" action

Comment: @nunopolonia it worked! please submit as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the development log.

Probably it will be something like `params[:post][:category]`

Answer (score 2):

Get your category like this:

```
params[:post][:category]
```